# Force Users To Relogin

Tags: php, mysql, logout

I need a solution that i can use to force a user to logout via the admin panel of word press any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [`wp_logout`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout) function will log a user out. Here's an example that will log someone out and redirect to the login page when the url contains the query string `?my_logout_flag`:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse52743_check_logout');

function wpse52743_check_logout(){
    if( isset( $_GET['my_logout_flag'] ) ) {
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    }
}
```